# Can't edit an account in MySQL Administrator on OS X

Tags: mac-osx, mysql

I'm running MySQL 5.5.20 on OS X 10.6.8. Using MySQL Administrator 1.2.12 (the latest) I am unable to edit any accounts. After successfully connecting to the database in MySQL Administrator, I go the Account tab, expand a user, and it just says "Loading...". It will stay on "Loading..." indefinitely.

[image]

The symptoms are almost identical to [user's experience](http://superfancy.net/coding/mysql-administrator-on-mac-osx-leopard-tips-and-tricks/#comment-1244) and [this MySQL bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17879) from 2006, which has since been closed (fixed?).

If I create a user and grant permissions to a schema, I get the error "Could not save changes to the use", which [came up in 2005 as a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14024) (now closed).

How do I edit MySQL accounts using MySQL Administrator?

Comment: Sure seems like a bug in that client application, and not in the MySQL server.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Very, very frustrating.